# Bind Jquery event on controls that have visible set to false

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a GridView which is inside a Panel control.Panel is initially set to `Visible="False"`.I want to bind some JQuery Event on GridView control like-

> $('#<%=Grd.ClientID%>').click(function(){
>   //Do some stuff
>   });

But Event is not binding due the Visibility of the Control.

Is there any way to so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '#<%=Grd.ClientID%>', function() {
    //...
});
```

See the **Direct and delegated events** section of the [`on()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).